# Ruby all by all matrix

Tags: ruby, matrix

I have strings s1,s2,s3,s4 and I want to do all by all comparison, so want to compare s1 with s2,s3,s4 and s2 with s3,s4 and s3 with s4, what is the best way to do that.

Something like a for loop?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to sort them? 'I want to do all by all comparison' makes little sense. Comparing what?

Comment: I like to compare strings s1 with the other strings, and s2 with other strings etc. it's just comparing two strings at a time but like to compare all strings with each other.

Answer (score 2):

See the Ruby [`Array#combination` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```ruby
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.combination(2) do |x,y|
  # Compare X to Y
end
```

Comment: Ruby 1.8.7 does have [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-combination).